# Animate an <img> element up and down +- 5px infinitely when the page is fully loaded. Where should I start looking for how I can accomplish this?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

I'm attempting to find anything that might accomplish this in jQuery but am having no luck. Would anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?

EDIT: What I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wiggley-caret').animate({ top: '-10px' }, 200);
});
```

Which, I would think, would animate it up -10px on page load, over a span of 200 milliseconds. It just does nothing. Plus, even if I do get it to work in that manner, it won't repeat infinitely (go back down 10px, then back up 10px, then back down... etc). So I don't really know how I can accomplish that either.

Edit: Got it, thanks @Jnatalzia - see it in action: http://topsecret.phasesolutions.ca/

EDIT 2: The solution:

Adding `position: relative;` to the element, and the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.wiggley-caret').animate({ top: '-=15px' }, 550);
        $('.wiggley-caret').animate({ top: '+=15px' }, 550);
    }, 1100);
});
```

Comment: EDIT: Added code that I've tried

Comment: This could be accomplished with [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't have a position setting on your element. In your CSS put

```
.wiggley-caret{position:relative;}
```

Then you have to do `-=` instead of just `-`. Your code will look like this, and should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wiggley-caret').animate({ top: '-=10px' }, 200);
});
```

You can then add in the functionality to go back up after that animation is done and call the function again.

Comment: Got it, thanks! See it in action: http://topsecret.phasesolutions.ca/

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it infinitely:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hMEKZ/)

```
function animup() {
    $('.wiggley-caret').animate({ top: '-=10px' }, 200, animdown);
}

function animdown() {
    $('.wiggley-caret').animate({ top: '+=10px' }, 200, animup);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    animup();
});
```